# Aligning Aside & Section Problems

Tags: html, css

Why are my aside tags are at the bottom of the page they wont come up next to the section why is this? I want 3 columns next to each other.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#header h1 {
    font-size: 67px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#main_body {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#section {
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#aside_right {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#aside_left {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Clean Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <h1>Clean Template</h1>
        </header>
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Main Body Beginning -->
        <div id="main_body">
            <section id="section">
                <article class="article_1">
                    <hgroup class="article_hgroup">
                        <h1>Article Title</h1>
                        <h2>Article Subtitle</h2>
                    </hgroup>
                    <p class="article_p">
                        Aut aute deserunt admodum, irure cernantur comprehenderit qui vidisse cillum 
                        elit doctrina quem de velit litteris in consectetur. Cernantur sint aliqua 
                        deserunt varias ubi veniam tempor distinguantur. Occaecat do occaecat ad elit 
                        vidisse de occaecat. Aut fugiat sempiternum, ut tamen veniam sint senserit de 
                        laboris ita commodo, a eram admodum ad nam de praesentibus, quo aut cillum amet 
                        minim, summis eiusmod e enim fugiat, culpa nescius familiaritatem. Si o 
                        transferrem, consequat e voluptate ea consequat legam tempor id qui dolor in 
                        labore, nostrud an minim consequat, senserit labore legam cupidatat lorem, quis 
                        iis ad aliqua tempor in de esse occaecat. Legam quibusdam ubi quem elit, ex 
                        consequat non doctrina e si noster proident an qui aute dolor hic excepteur.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_footer">
                        <h3>Written by: John Doe | July 1st, 2015</h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article class="article_2">
                    <hgroup class="article_hgroup">
                        <h1>Article Title 2</h1>
                        <h2>Article Subtitle 2</h2>
                    </hgroup>
                    <p class="article_p">
                        Aut aute deserunt admodum, irure cernantur comprehenderit qui vidisse cillum 
                        elit doctrina quem de velit litteris in consectetur. Cernantur sint aliqua 
                        deserunt varias ubi veniam tempor distinguantur. Occaecat do occaecat ad elit 
                        vidisse de occaecat. Aut fugiat sempiternum, ut tamen veniam sint senserit de 
                        laboris ita commodo, a eram admodum ad nam de praesentibus, quo aut cillum amet 
                        minim, summis eiusmod e enim fugiat, culpa nescius familiaritatem. Si o 
                        transferrem, consequat e voluptate ea consequat legam tempor id qui dolor in 
                        labore, nostrud an minim consequat, senserit labore legam cupidatat lorem, quis 
                        iis ad aliqua tempor in de esse occaecat. Legam quibusdam ubi quem elit, ex 
                        consequat non doctrina e si noster proident an qui aute dolor hic excepteur.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_footer">
                        <h3>Written by: John Doe | July 1st, 2015</h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article class="article_3">
                    <hgroup class="article_hgroup">
                        <h1>Article Title 3</h1>
                        <h2>Article Subtitle 3</h2>
                    </hgroup>
                    <p class="article_p">
                        Aut aute deserunt admodum, irure cernantur comprehenderit qui vidisse cillum 
                        elit doctrina quem de velit litteris in consectetur. Cernantur sint aliqua 
                        deserunt varias ubi veniam tempor distinguantur. Occaecat do occaecat ad elit 
                        vidisse de occaecat. Aut fugiat sempiternum, ut tamen veniam sint senserit de 
                        laboris ita commodo, a eram admodum ad nam de praesentibus, quo aut cillum amet 
                        minim, summis eiusmod e enim fugiat, culpa nescius familiaritatem. Si o 
                        transferrem, consequat e voluptate ea consequat legam tempor id qui dolor in 
                        labore, nostrud an minim consequat, senserit labore legam cupidatat lorem, quis 
                        iis ad aliqua tempor in de esse occaecat. Legam quibusdam ubi quem elit, ex 
                        consequat non doctrina e si noster proident an qui aute dolor hic excepteur.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_footer">
                        <h3>Written by: John Doe | July 1st, 2015</h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
            </section>
            <aside id="aside_left">
                <article class="article_aside_1">
                    <h1>Article Header</h1>
                    <p>
                        Ut ne eram vidisse, noster se quibusdam non quae. Se admodum voluptatibus. Nulla 
                        ullamco tractavissent, possumus aliqua ex aliquip efflorescere te cupidatat 
                        tamen minim in labore ea hic possumus cohaerescant.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_aside_footer">
                        <h3><a href="#">Full Post</a></h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article class="article_aside_2">
                    <h1>Article Header 2</h1>
                    <p>
                        Ut ne eram vidisse, noster se quibusdam non quae. Se admodum voluptatibus. Nulla 
                        ullamco tractavissent, possumus aliqua ex aliquip efflorescere te cupidatat 
                        tamen minim in labore ea hic possumus cohaerescant.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_aside_footer">
                        <h3><a href="#">Full Post</a></h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article class="article_aside_3">
                    <h1>Article Header 3</h1>
                    <p>
                        Ut ne eram vidisse, noster se quibusdam non quae. Se admodum voluptatibus. Nulla 
                        ullamco tractavissent, possumus aliqua ex aliquip efflorescere te cupidatat 
                        tamen minim in labore ea hic possumus cohaerescant.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_aside_footer">
                        <h3><a href="#">Full Post</a></h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
            </aside>
            <aside id="aside_right">
                <article class="article_aside_1">
                    <h1>Article Header</h1>
                    <p>
                        Ut ne eram vidisse, noster se quibusdam non quae. Se admodum voluptatibus. Nulla 
                        ullamco tractavissent, possumus aliqua ex aliquip efflorescere te cupidatat 
                        tamen minim in labore ea hic possumus cohaerescant.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_aside_footer">
                        <h3><a href="#">Full Post</a></h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article class="article_aside_2">
                    <h1>Article Header 2</h1>
                    <p>
                        Ut ne eram vidisse, noster se quibusdam non quae. Se admodum voluptatibus. Nulla 
                        ullamco tractavissent, possumus aliqua ex aliquip efflorescere te cupidatat 
                        tamen minim in labore ea hic possumus cohaerescant.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_aside_footer">
                        <h3><a href="#">Full Post</a></h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <article class="article_aside_3">
                    <h1>Article Header 3</h1>
                    <p>
                        Ut ne eram vidisse, noster se quibusdam non quae. Se admodum voluptatibus. Nulla 
                        ullamco tractavissent, possumus aliqua ex aliquip efflorescere te cupidatat 
                        tamen minim in labore ea hic possumus cohaerescant.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="article_aside_footer">
                        <h3><a href="#">Full Post</a></h3>
                    </footer>
                </article>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Body Ending -->
        <footer id="footer">
            &copy; All Rights Reserved. | <a href="#">Legal</a>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post external JSFiddle link so we can modify it easily.

Comment: @wazaaaap But... there's a "Copy snippet to answer" button.

Comment: @Basic: Why would you expect them to be anywhere but at the bottom? That's where you put them in your HTML.

Comment: @Joseph But...i am talking about external JSFiddle link.

Comment: @wazaaaap Generally we discourage users from using external sources when internal ones are available.  This reduces the possibility of a question becoming less relevant in the future because of a broken link or expired content.  I don't see any reason why the original poster should take his code snippet off site.  If that's the tool you prefer, you can also very easily copy and paste it yourself.

Comment: (Note that I only added the snippet afterwards, but I also did it to keep it on SO itself, without having to refer to external resources.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats only affect the content that follows the floating elements. So in your case, since the asides are floating at the end, they won’t affect your `section`. Instead, you will have to reorder them, so the floating elements are first:

```
<div id="main_body">
    <aside id="aside_left"></aside>
    <aside id="aside_right"></aside>

    <!-- section after the floating elements -->
    <section id="section"></section>
</div>
```

Btw. the next time you post such a question, you should trim out all the content that makes it hard to figure out your structure. Instead of putting actual content inside the boxes, you can just give them fixed sizes (and maybe some background color so we know which box is what).